# xml parsing error (xpath, HTMLagilitypack)

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse an xml. All nodes have opening and closing tags except one node that in some lines in only has this tag:     `<persons/>`

In most of the time it appears like this: `<persons> ... </persons>`
I cannot get values from the xml when this node is not closing like this

Here is my code:

```
foreach (HtmlNode man in bm.SelectNodes(".//persons"))
 {
  //store values
 }
```

How can I overcome this issue? Even if some nodes are like this at the start:

```
<persons> </persons>
```

if there is a tag like this in the middle of the file

```
<persons/>
```

I cannot get the remaining `<persons> </persons>` values from the remaining lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you using htmlnode? xmlnode would be just fine.

Or else, show more codes.

Did you step through the line? Did you encounter any error?

try this:

```
    internal string ParseXML()
    {
        string ppl = "";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
        foreach (XmlElement node in doc.SelectNodes(".//person"))
        {
            string text = node.InnerText; //or loop through its children as well
            ppl += text;
        }
        return ppl;
    }
```

Comment: that is fine, then you shouldn't use htmlnode, you can use XmlElement for doc.SelectNodes(".//person")